# How to make a PHP calculator with 3 variables

Tags: php

So for school, I was tasked with creating a simple PHP calculator that used 3 variables. I thought that I would use switch statements to do all the calculations for functions but run into the issues when dealing with Order of Operations. After several hours and multiple attempts I am forced to admit I'm stumped... Any suggestions?

```php
<?php
// function to calculate and return result
function calculate($x, $y, $op) { 
    // calculate $prod using switch (case) statement
    switch($op1) {
        case '+':
            $prod1 = $x + $y;
            break;
        case '-':
            $prod1 = $x - $y;
            break;
        case '*':
            $prod1 = $x * $y;
            break;
        case '/':
            if ($y == 0) {$prod1 = "&#8734";}
            else {$prod1 = $x / $y;}
    // return the result
    return $prod1;
    }
}
function calculate2($prod1, $z, $op2) { 
    // calculate $prod2 using switch (case) statement
        switch($op2) {
        case '+':
            $prod2 = $prod1 + $z;
            break;
        case '-':
            $prod2 = $prod1 - $z;
            break;
        case '*':
            $prod2 = $prod1 * $z;
            break;
        case '/':
            if ($z == 0) {$prod2 = "&#8734";}
            else {$prod2 = $prod1 / $z;}
    }
    // return the result
    return $prod2;
}
function calculate3($x, $prod2, $op1) { 
    // calculate $prod using switch (case) statement
        switch($op2) {
        case '+':
            $prod2 = $x + $prod1;
            break;
        case '-':
            $prod2 = $x - $prod1;
    }
    // return the result
    return $prod3;
}
function calculate4($y, $z, $op2) { 
    // calculate $prod using switch (case) statement
        switch($op2) {
        case '*':
            $prod2 = $y * $z;
            break;
        case '/':
            if ($z == 0) {$prod2 = "&#8734";}
            else {$prod2 = $y / $z;}
    }
    // return the result
    return $prod2;
}
// declare all variables
$x = 0;
$y = 0;
$z = 0;
$prod1 = 0;
$prod2 = 0;
$prod3 = 0;
$op1 = '';
$op2 = '';


// grab the form values from $_GET hash
extract($_GET);

?>

  <html>

  <head>
    <title>PHP Calculator Version 2.12</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <h3>PHP Calculator (Version 2.12)</h3>

    <form method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

      x = <input type="text" name="x" size="5" value="<?php print $x; ?>" /> op1 =
      <select name="op">
                <option value="+" <?php if ($op=='+') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>+</option>
                <option value="-" <?php if ($op=='-') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>-</option>
                <option value="*" <?php if ($op=='*') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>*</option>
                <option value="/" <?php if ($op=='/') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>/</option>
            </select> y = <input type="text" name="y" size="5" value="<?php  print $y; ?>" /> op2 =
      <select name="op2">
                <option value="+" <?php if ($op2=='+') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>+</option>
                <option value="-" <?php if ($op2=='-') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>-</option>
                <option value="*" <?php if ($op2=='*') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>*</option>
                <option value="/" <?php if ($op2=='/') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>/</option>
            </select> z = <input type="text" name="z" size="5" value="<?php print $z; ?>" />
      <input type="submit" name="calc" value="Calculate" />
    </form>

    <?php
        if(isset($calc)) {
            // check that $x & $y are numeric
            if (is_numeric($x) && is_numeric($y) && is_numeric($z)) {
                // check PEMDAS
                if ($op1 == '*' or '/') {
                    $prod1 = calculate($x, $y, $op1);
                    $prod2 = calculate2($prod1, $z, $op2);  
                }
                else if ($op2 == '*' or '/') {
                     $prod2 = calculate4($y, $z, $op2);
                     $prod3 = calculate3($x, $prod2, $op1);
                }
                else 
                    $prod1 = calculate($x, $y, $op1);
                    $prod2 = calculate2($prod1, $z, $op2);

                // print the result 
                echo "<p>$x $op $y $op2 $z = $prod2 </p>";
            }
            else {
                // unaccepatable values
                echo "<p>x, y, and z values are required to be numeric ... 
                         please re-enter values</p>";
            }
        }
    ?>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: The last argument of `calculate()` is `$op` but your switch statement uses `$op1`. That's not going to work. `calculate3()` has a similar problem. You have to solve these basic problems before you give up.

Comment: Ok so I fixed that - but the real issue is that in my if /else if statements $prod1 isn't holding a value after the calculation(). So when I try to calculate using $prod1 it is equal to 0

Comment: I did notice other bugs, like `($op1 == '*' or '/')`, this should be: `(($op1 == '*') or ($op1 == '/'))`, and there's a second similar one. Solve **all** bugs first, before you give up. Test thoroughly. Also check if all `{` are matched by `}` in the right places. One set of `{`...`}` seems to be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is not that bad for a beginner, but it still needs some work. Why would you use multiple functions doing more or less the same calculation? You are a ware, that you can call any function multiple time?

Then, check your code. You have a lot of variable mistakes, as you name them different.

Also your variable naming is not so well readable. Give the variables names, so you know what they are supposed to be. On this small code level, this is not that big of a deal. If you work with a lot of code, a good naming can make up a lot!

If you plan to stay on to programming, you want to train yourself to check those issues early. This will save you a lot of time in the future, as you will be trained to do this automatically.

I have more or less corrected your code. I have written some comments to hint out parts and fixes, so you understand what has changed and why.

If you get grades for this calculator project, keep in mind there is still a lot of stuff you can do better. At least if you want to get the best grade.

- Check your naming.
- Address security issues. (If anyone sees you do this as a beginner,they will be impressed!)
- Commenting your code. You have comments, but they are not enough. Comment anything possible so people understand what the code is doing just by reading the comment.

Some corrected code:

```
<?php
// you only need one function. why would you need a lot of functions doing the same?
function calculate($x, $y, $op) {
    // calculate $prod using switch (case) statement
    switch($op) {
        case '+':
            $prod = $x + $y;
            break;
        case '-':
            $prod = $x - $y;
            break;
        case '*':
            $prod = $x * $y;
            break;
        case '/':
            if ($y == 0) {$prod = "&#8734";}
            else {$prod = $x / $y;}
            break;
    }

    // do return your result AFTER the switch. else you will not get any results in most cases
    return $prod;
}

// you can do this, but keep in mind, this is more or less a security issue!
// you may want to check how to work with $_GET variables. as it is for school work, it is not critical yet,
// but if you plan to use php in future you may want to have a look at some ways to avoid problems.
extract($_GET);

// in this example is no need to predefine the variables as you had it, as wich each post the value get lost and it only uses the information from $_GET

?>
 <html>

  <head>
    <title>PHP Calculator Version 2.12</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <h3>PHP Calculator (Version 2.12)</h3>

    <form method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

      x = <input type="text" name="x" size="5" value="<?php print $x; ?>" /> op1 =
      <select name="op1">
                <option value="+" <?php if ($op1=='+') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>+</option>
                <option value="-" <?php if ($op1=='-') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>-</option>
                <option value="*" <?php if ($op1=='*') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>*</option>
                <option value="/" <?php if ($op1=='/') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>/</option>
            </select> y = <input type="text" name="y" size="5" value="<?php  print $y; ?>" /> op2 =
      <select name="op2">
                <option value="+" <?php if ($op2=='+') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>+</option>
                <option value="-" <?php if ($op2=='-') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>-</option>
                <option value="*" <?php if ($op2=='*') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>*</option>
                <option value="/" <?php if ($op2=='/') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>/</option>
            </select> z = <input type="text" name="z" size="5" value="<?php print $z; ?>" />
      <input type="submit" name="calc" value="Calculate" />
    </form>

   <?php
        if(isset($calc)) {
            if (is_numeric($x) && is_numeric($y) && is_numeric($z)) {
                // if you use OR / AND or any other operator, make sure both sides have a counterpart to work with.
                if ($op1 == '*' or $op1 == '/') {
                    // you can use the same function multiple times as seen below
                    $prod1 = calculate($x, $y, $op1);
                    $prod2 = calculate($prod1, $z, $op2);
                }
                else if ($op2 == '*' or $op2 == '/') {
                    $prod1 = calculate($y, $z, $op2);
                    $prod2 = calculate($x, $prod1, $op1);
                }
                else {
                    $prod1 = calculate($x, $y, $op1);
                    $prod2 = calculate($prod1, $z, $op2);
                }

                // make sure what you print does also exist!
                echo "<p>$x $op1 $y $op2 $z = $prod2 </p>";
            }
            else {
                // unaccepatable values
                echo "<p>x, y, and z values are required to be numeric ... 
                         please re-enter values</p>";
            }
        }
    ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

you really only need 1 function to do the calculations, x holds a value to your next calculation and the result to your previous one

```
<html>
   <head>
     <title>PHP Calculator Version 2.12</title>
   </head>
   <body>
<?php
function calculate($x, $y, $op) {
    switch($op) {
        case '+':
            $result = $x + $y;
            break;
        case '-':
            $result = $x - $y;
            break;
        case '*':
            $result = $x * $y;
            break;
        case '/':
            if ($y == 0) {
                $result = "&#8734";
            } else {
                $result = $x / $y;
            }
    }
    return $result;
}

extract($_REQUEST);

$x = calculate($x, $y, $op);
?>
   <body>
    <form method="get"">
      x = <input type="text" name="x" size="5" value="<?php print $x; ?>" /><br />
      op = <select name="op">
        <option value="+" <?php if ($op === '+') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>+</option>
        <option value="-" <?php if ($op === '-') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>-</option>
        <option value="*" <?php if ($op === '*') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>*</option>
        <option value="/" <?php if ($op === '/') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>/</option>
      </select><br />
      y = <input type="text" name="y" size="5" value="<?php  print $y; ?>" /><br />
      <input type="submit" name="calc" value="Calculate" /><br />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

NOW, for fun, write a fraction calculator! :)

Comment: we just made the same. If i knew that I could have saved me that work :)

Comment: haha, lovin' your work @natheriel - I didn't understand the need for op1 _and_ op2, way too complicated for me

Comment: hehe, I also had to think about it. It just seems that he tried to make it look more complicated. If you have 2+2/2, you first have to use the second operator (2/2=1), after that the first with the result of the second (2+1=3) to get the correct result. Classic math stuff like multiply and divide before plus and minus calculation.

Comment: ahhhh, I see!! I'm a 1 operator at a time kinda guy! old HP calculators used to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation, you actually have to *think* about the order of your calculations :-O

Comment: The goal of the exercise was to use 3 variables in order to attempt to use order of operations. So although you can do it with 1 operator the exercise was to use 2.

Comment: @WeeZel +1 for your effort ^^'

Comment: cheers @natheriel, when the title said "How to make a PHP calculator with 3 **variables**" I thought: $x; $y and $op... that's why I made the comment about $op1 and $op2! d'oh! ;-) lesson learned: check example code to see what they are trying to achieve. oh, and a upvote from me for your answer

Comment: @WeeZel its not that mine got selected. I just want to give credit to your work too. ;-)  You spent time as well.